# My screensaver is stopping screen suspend but I don't want it to

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, power-management

I made a screensaver in .Net 4.0. It basically just moves the bits in an image around and displays it using .Invalidate on a timer and overriding the onPaint event.

So far, it works great - however - I noticed one problem with it.

It's stopping the monitor from suspending after the suspend timeout. Since I installed it, my monitor stays on 24/7 now.

The thing is, I didn't do anything to specifically stop power savings features - and I've made sure that my computer's power savings settings are set (they are). So then I chose another screensaver just to be sure the settings were still working. The monitor suspended after the timeout.

What do I need to do then to play nice with power management? I searched for this answer on Google and everything I found is how to block power management and I didn't explicitly block it! I just want the suspend to be allowed when it's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my program to "play nice". I don't know why this works and the original code didn't, but this not only works - it actually makes the program more "power savings" friendly because it reduces CPU cycles by not doing calculations after the screen suspends. In short, I preview the WndProc messages and look for the monitor is being suspended message and once it's received, I stop redrawing until it resumes (it's possible to resume and have the screensaver still active).

Code changes:

```
    // Field Definitions
    /// <summary>
    /// Constants that relate to the WndProc messages we wish to intercept and evaluate.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules", "SA1310:FieldNamesMustNotContainUnderscore", Justification = "Standard practice to use this naming style for Win32 API Constants.")]
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112, SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets whether we are suspended. Should coincide with whether the display is turned on or not.
    /// </summary>
    private bool isSuspended = false;


    // New overridden method
    /// <summary>
    /// Intercepts WndProc messages. We are looking for the screen suspend activity. From it, we will return that we are able to suspend and we ourselves will suspend.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">Message to be checked.</param>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            // The 0x000F bits are used to indicate the specific state and must be ignored to see if this is a monitor power event.
            if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFF0) == SC_MONITORPOWER)
            {
                switch (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0x000F)
                {
                    case -1:
                        // Display powering on - resume operation
#if DEBUG
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Display powered on.");
#endif
                        this.isSuspended = false;
                        break;
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        // Display being powered off - suspend operation
#if DEBUG
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Display suspended");
#endif
                        this.isSuspended = true;
                        break;
                    default:
#if DEBUG
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Unknown power state: {0}", (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0x000F).ToString("0")));
#endif
                        // Assuming that unknown values mean to power off. This is a WAG.
                        this.isSuspended = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }


    // Change to my refreshing timer.
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the refresh timer ticks. This invalidates the form, forcing it to be redrawn, which creates a framerate for us.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Who called this method.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event Arguments.</param>
    private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.isSuspended)
        {
            // Program is in suspended mode, so don't do anything this update.
            return;
        }

        // Program is not suspended, so invalidate the client area so it can be painted again.
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Making this change stops all the redrawing when a suspend is called (and stops the GDI+ calculations) and after making it, the screensaver "behaves" with power management settings.

Comment: Very cool - if you don't mind I'll probably use this as a template for changing a monitoring app we have, which hits the database pretty hard when it runs, and pointlessly so when the screen isn't shown anyway.

Comment: I don't mind a bit and it's partially your own success already! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance accidentally trap the 0xF170 (SC_MONITORPOWER) sub-command of [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360.aspx)?

Comment: To answer this comment, no I wasn't. However, I considered doing so and suspending the drawing routine after receiving the message. This consideration eventually led to the resolution which I'm now going to add and accept as an answer. Still, you were a key stepping stone along the way and I wanted to let you know that as I voted you up.

Comment: Glad I could be at least of some help ;)